# El curioso caso de los planetas en el diccionario

Tags: definiciones, historia, nombres-propios, ciencia

Me resulta muy curiosa la definición de *planeta* en los diccionarios antiguos, y de lo que voy a mencionar a continuación seguramente se puedan sacar varias preguntas. Vamos por orden.

Definición de *planeta* en 1611:

> PLANETAS, siete cuerpos celestiales, que en sus orbes particulares tiene cada una su propio movimiento contrario al del primer mobil, y por esta razon se llaron erraneas, a diferéncia de las demas estrellas que estan fixas en el cielo estrellado, sin mudar jamas distancias una de otra.

Covarrubias no entra a dar más detalles, por lo que nos quedamos sin saber cuáles eran esos "siete cuerpos celestiales". La respuesta nos la da la RAE en 1737:

> PLANETA. Nombre que se da à los siete cuerpos celestes, que en sus orbes particulares tiene cada uno su propio movimiento, contrario al del primer mobil: y por esta razón se llamaron errantes, à diferencia de las demás estrellas que estan fixas en el Cielo. Son sus nombres Sol, Luna, Marte, Mercurio, Jupiter, Venus y Saturno, de quien tomaron nombres los siete días de la semána.

Recordemos que en 1611, mientras Covarrubias presentaba su diccionario, Galileo estaba en Roma presentando sus descubrimientos que probaban la teoría heliocéntrica, y que por entonces Kepler hacía dos años ya que había establecido su primera ley, que decía que los planetas se desplazan alrededor del sol. Hacia 1737 ya había pasado el suficiente tiempo como para que los académicos aceptaran que el sol y la luna no eran planetas. Sobre todo porque en 1737 la RAE definía *satélite* como:

> SATELITES. Quatro Estrellas pequeñas, que siempre acompañan al Planeta Júpiter, y otras cinco que andan alrededór de Saturno.

Deberían haber incluido la Luna, que se sabía que giraba alrededor de la Tierra, en esta categoría, y no en la de planetas.

Pero vamos más allá. Buscando en el diccionario cada uno de esos "siete planetas", vemos que en sus definiciones del *Diccionario de Autoridades* se dice:

> SOL. El principal de los siete Planetas, Rey de los Astros, y la antorcha mas brillante de los Cielos, que nos alumbra, y vivifica.
>   LUNA. El menor de los dos luminares que puso Dios en el Cielo para que presidiesse à la noche. Los Astrónomos la cuentan por el septimo de los Planetas, por ser su Orbe el inferior de todos, y mas cercano à la tierra.
>   MARTE. El tercero de los siete Planétas.
>   MERCURIO. El sexto de los siete Planétas.
>   JUPITER. Uno de los siete Planétas.
>   VENUS. El tercero de los Planétas.
>   SATURNO. El séptimo y último de los Planetas.

Así pues, recopilando, tenemos que los planetas son, por orden:

1. Sol.
2. ??
3. Marte y Venus.
4. ??
5. ??
6. Mercurio.
7. Saturno y la Luna.

Orden sin especificar: Júpiter.

Esto es lo que pasaba cuando los redactores del *Diccionario de Autoridades* no se ponían de acuerdo entre ellos. Imagino que cada uno siguió un orden diferente y por eso las definiciones se solapan. Así que ahí van las preguntas:

- ¿Por qué en pleno siglo XVIII el diccionario seguía considerando al sol y a la luna como "planetas"? ¿Cómo evolucionó esta definición y cuándo dejaron de definirse como tal?
- Por rellenar los huecos en la lista anterior, ¿cuál era el orden correcto por el que se designaban los "planetas" en el siglo XVIII?
- *Off-topic* y por tanto preguntado en otro sitio: [¿cuál era la definición de *planeta* en inglés en la misma época?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/430320/280768)

Comment: Haz +1 en este comentario si leyendo esta pregunta he conseguido sacarte una sonrisa. :-)

Comment: I do not understand why you write Sin clasificar: Júpiter.when the displayed text above contains that planet.

Comment: @mdewey because the definition of Jupiter says "one of the planets", but it does not specify the order.

Comment: Se me hace que esta pregunta está fuera de tema para un blog que trata del idioma español.  Una pregunta histórica interesante, pero sin embargo fuera de tema.

Comment: quizá como pregunta extra, ¿cuál es el *primer mobil* al que hace referencia Covarrubias y la RAE?

Comment: pues el orden son 
sol- 
luna- 
marte- 
mercurio- 
jupiter- 
venus- 
Saturno- 

por que asi.. habria que preguntarle a los astronomos de aquella epoca

Comment: @Alicia por supuesto que no, la Tierra es el centro del Universo, como todo el mundo sabe. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vamos por partes.

- **¿Por qué en pleno siglo XVIII el diccionario seguía considerando al sol y a la luna como "planetas"?**

Para la Iglesia Católica el heliocentrismo quedó asociado al caso Galileo y se convirtió en un problema. Durante mucho tiempo se lo aceptó pero sólo como un artificio matemático para facilitar los cálculos astronómicos. Llegado un cierto punto no se podía sostener a nivel científico la posición geocéntrica como reflejo de la realidad, pero recién en 1758 fue levantada la prohibición eclesiástica de publicar libros que sostuviesen la teoría heliocéntrica, y sólo en 1822 Pío VII permitió que se imprimieran tales libros en Roma (aunque para ese momento ya no importaba mucho).

Dada esta resistencia de la autoridad religiosa, no sería de extrañar que los diccionarios hayan recogido el uso tradicional por tanto tiempo. Quizá también haya ocurrido que los diccionarios, no siendo textos enciclopédicos, prefiriesen transcribir por simple inercia las definiciones antiguas. Los lexicógrafos quizá no se consideraban responsables de transmitir conocimientos científicos correctos, sino de reflejar los usos conocidos.

Alguien que sabe del tema [explica](http://www.elmundo.es/ciencia/2016/06/26/576d240422601df7468b4574.html) (sobre el heliocentrismo):

> La Iglesia Católica mostró una actitud inicialmente positiva. De
>   hecho, la reforma del calendario realizada bajo el Papa Gregorio XIII,
>   promulgada en 1582 en Portugal, España y los estados de la península
>   Itálica, estuvo basada en las tablas Pruténicas de Erasmus Reingold.
>   Esta herramienta astronómica fue publicada en 1551 y fue la primera
>   basada en el heliocentrismo copernicano, a pesar de asumir que solo
>   era un "artificio matemático" para "salvar las apariencias", un
>   conveniente eufemismo que se utilizaría en numerosas ocasiones, tanto
>   desde la Antigüedad como en el propio prólogo de "De revolutionibus".
>   Al final, tras los descubrimientos realizados con el telescopio a
>   partir de 1610 y la intervención de Galileo Galilei en el terreno de
>   la teología, varias obras heliocéntricas serían prohibidas hace justo
>   400 años, y el texto de Copérnico fue sometido a un interdicto hasta
>   su "corrección".

- **Por rellenar los huecos en la lista anterior, ¿cuál era el orden correcto por el que se designaban los "planetas" en el siglo XVIII?**

Los planetas clásicos de la Antigüedad eran los siete objetos astronómicos móviles visibles a ojo desnudo: la Luna, Mercurio, Venus, el Sol, Marte, Júpiter y Saturno. Evidentemente los redactores del *Diccionario de Autoridades* no tenían muy claro el orden.

Una ordenación habitual era el de la astrología griega, con raíces babilónicas, conocida como el "orden caldeo": Saturno, Júpiter, Marte, el Sol, Venus, Mercurio, la Luna. De éste deriva el de las [horas planetarias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_hours), el sistema que nos dio los nombres de los días de la semana. Ninguno de estos dos parece coincidir con el (incompleto y confuso) del *Diccionario de Autoridades*.

P.S.: La definición de *satélite* también está ridículamente atrasada. Si bien ya acepta que Júpiter tiene cuatro cuerpos subplanetarios girando en su torno, para 1737 ya se habían descubierto y nombrado cinco de los satélites de Saturno.

Answer (score 1):

Revisando el [mapa de diccionarios](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios), en el siglo XIX ya se empezó a utilizar un término planetario más... *evolucionado*. En 1817 un planeta es un *Cuerpo celeste opaco que solo brilla por la luz refleja del sol, al rededor del cual describe su órbita mas ó menos circular ó elíptica con un movimiento propio y periódico.* Ahora, desde hace 100 años incluían la versión de los planetas de Ptolomeo o Tolomeo, los cuales se presentan en órden de *Luna, Mercurio, Venus, el Sol, Marte, Júpiter y Saturno.* aunque el órden solo coinciden 2 de los 7...