# ¿Por qué escribimos "móvil" con "v", si viene del latín "mobĭlis" y el resto de idiomas mantuvieron la "b"?

Tags: etimología, ortografía, latín

El otro día Charlie planteó [El curioso caso de los planetas en el diccionario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24122/1674) y en ella vimos fragmentos en los que se definía *planeta* a lo largo de los siglos y diccionarios.

Definición de *planeta* en 1611:

> PLANETAS, siete cuerpos celestiales, que en sus orbes particulares tiene cada una su propio movimiento contrario al del primer **mobil**, y por esta razon se llaron erraneas, a diferéncia de las demas estrellas que estan fixas en el cielo estrellado, sin mudar jamas distancias una de otra.

y luego la RAE en 1737:

> PLANETA. Nombre que se da à los siete cuerpos celestes, que en sus orbes particulares tiene cada uno su propio movimiento, contrario al del primer **mobil**: y por esta razón se llamaron errantes, à diferencia de las demás estrellas que estan fixas en el Cielo. Son sus nombres Sol, Luna, Marte, Mercurio, Jupiter, Venus y Saturno, de quien tomaron nombres los siete días de la semána.

Como veis, destaco que se mencione ***mobil*** para referirse a ***móvil***. En efecto, resulta que por aquel entonces su ortografía era más cercana a su origen:

> [**móvil**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PxcFux4)
> *Del lat. mobĭlis.*

En el CORPUS encuentro referencias a *mobil* en textos solamente del siglo XVII, aunque finalmente hay uno de 1764:

> "Que concurran los Graduados no matriculados, y se les tenga como á los demas de continua residencia"; en la que estaba comprendida la percepcion de Propina, pues perciviendolas estos, como las percivian, de necesidad devian recivirlas los otros, y respecto de que estos hechos manifestaban, que el *mobil* de estos recursos haviais sido Vos, que os haviais descubierto abiertamente, con el empeño de sostenerle (...)

en lo que parece un texto esencialmente jurídico (*R. pr. del mismo con orden de no matricular a los graduados complutenses si no residen conforme a es*), por lo que podría descartarse por ser la rama de la lengua menos permeable a las novedades (¡opino!).

Además, a partir de cierto momento pasó a tener el acento prosódico en la primera sílaba, tal y como muestra el [Mapa de diccionarios](https://apps2.rae.es/ntllet/SrvltGUILoginNtlletPub)

| palabra | diccionarios |
| --- | --- |
| móvil | 1817, 1884, 1925, 1992, 2001 |
| movil | 1780 |

Así pues, las dudas son dos:

- ¿por qué dejó de usarse ***mobil*** y se comenzó a usar con ***v*** y cambiando la sílaba tónica?
- ¿qué relación puede tener en comparación con el resto de idiomas, que siguen usando la *b* (*mobile* en inglés, *mòbil* en catalán, *mobil* en alemán...)? De hecho, de las 36 lenguas que incorpora [Wiktionary en su artículo *mobilis*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mobilis), solamente en portugués (*móvel*, aunque también *móbil*) y castellano (*móvil*) se usa *v*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

El origen de palabras como *móvil* o *movilidad*, que en tiempos se escribieron, como dices, *mobil* y *mobilidad*, es en última instancia el verbo latino *movere*. La composición de este con sufijos como *-bilis* o *-bilitas* hizo que en los compuestos pasara a usarse la *b*.

Sin embargo, la influencia de la palabra original *mover* fue siempre fuerte, y ya el diccionario de la RAE de 1780 recoge *movil* y no *mobil*, a pesar de que en 1734 era precisamente al revés. Hay que tener en cuenta que otros derivados de *mover* sí se escribían con *v*, como *movedizo*, *movible* o incluso *movimiento*, lo que aumentaba la confusión. Al final, lo que tuvo lugar fue un proceso de normalización de los derivados de *mover*, para que todos usaran la misma consonante.

Fíjate además que *movedizo* y *movible* eran sinónimas de *móbil*, tal y como recoge el Terreros y Pando de 1787:

> MÓBIL, MOVIBLE, MOVEDIZO, adj. lo que se puede mover, ó es susceptible de movimiento.

Sin embargo, este diccionario mencionado es el último que recoge la palabra con *b*, dado que aún aparecía en algunos textos como el que muestras de 1764. Para entonces el proceso de normalización ya estaba casi completado.

Sobre el cambio de sílaba tónica, efectivamente la RAE afirmaba en 1741 en su primera ortografía que las palabras solo debían acentuarse si la sílaba tónica era diferente de la habitual según la terminación. Si la palabra acababa en vocal distinta de *s*, lo común era que fuesen agudas y por tanto debían acentuarse si eran llanas, y pone el ejemplo de *fácil*. Por la misma regla, *móvil* debería acentuarse pero no aparece así hasta la edición de 1783 del diccionario. Sin embargo, si te fijas en el *Diccionario de Autoridades*, ninguna palabra está recogida con tilde. Ni siquiera *fácil*, dada como ejemplo por la *Ortographia* de palabra con tilde. En el Terreros y Pando sí la lleva (en su versión *móbil*) y otros diccionarios anteriores también la registran con tilde, empezando por el Vittori de 1609. Eso me hace pensar que la palabra realmente no cambió su sílaba tónica, sino que hasta un determinado año no se normalizaron las reglas de acentuación y la tilde fue apareciendo y desapareciendo en la palabra. Si buscas en el CORDE "móbil" aparecen más de 50 registros ya en el siglo XVI.

Acerca de por qué otras palabras como *mueble* sí conservan la *b*, imagino que será por la conversión de *o* a *ue*, que hace que la palabra se distancie del original *mover* y por tanto no le afectó la normalización, por no hablar de que, como comenta @guifa, el grupo *vl* no existe en castellano. Hay que tener en cuenta que *mueble* ya existía con el grupo *ue* allá por el siglo XIII. Y el caso de *mobiliario*, es una palabra más reciente. Su primera aparición en diccionarios fue en el siglo XIX y aparece como importada del francés, luego entró en nuestro idioma pasada la normalización de los derivados de *mover*.

Comment: ¿Qué pasa con mueble, mobiliario, etc. que también derivan de *mobilis*?

Comment: @blonfu En el caso de *mueble*, la combinación *vl* simplemente no se hace en castellano :-)  Y *mobiliario*, siendo palabra relacionada, quedó con lo mismo (o bien por influencia del francés, que recoge *meubles* y *mobilier*)

Comment: @blonfu pues eso, lo que dice guifa más lo que te he añadido en la respuesta. :-)

Comment: Enlace para complementar la excelente respuesta: [¿Qué revisiones ha tenido la ortografía española?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/10329/1674)