# ¿Qué errores contiene o ha contenido el Diccionario de la Lengua de la RAE?

Tags: dle, curiosidades

¿Qué errores contiene o ha contenido el Diccionario de la Lengua? No me refiero a lo que ahora consideramos errores por avances en el conocimiento, sino a entradas o definiciones que ya eran erróneas en ese momento.

Comment: No entiendo como tiene sentido poner ésta  pregunta aqui.

Comment: @saki No hay vote to close visible. Muchas preguntas son interesantes pero ningún otro sitio (los dos de inglés, el de portugués y el de francés) permite perguntas pedagógicas generales.

Answer (score 6):

> <sup><sub>**Respuesta CW, siéntete libre de añadir la información que consideres necesaria.**</sub></sup>

---

En el DLE de 1956 (y anteriores) se recoge, en la entrada **número** la siguiente definición (negritas mías):

> **Números amigos**
> *Aritm.* Dícese del par de números en que cada uno de ellos es igual a la suma de las partes alícuotas del otro. **No se conocen más que tres pares** en que se verifique esa propiedad y son: el 220 y 284; el 17296 y 18416 y el 9363584 y 9437056.

Sin embargo, en [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmeros_amigos) se recogen otras parejas (1184 y 1210; 6232, 6368) conocidas desde mucho antes, y en [Lista de números amigos entre 1 y 20 000 000](http://www.vaxasoftware.com/doc_edu/mat/numamigos_esp.pdf), **más de 140 parejas**.

---

A pesar de que hacía más de 100 años que se había demostrado la teoría heliocéntrica, en 1737 la RAE definía en el *Autoridades* la voz *[planeta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24122/12637)* como (negritas mías):

> PLANETA. Nombre que se da à los siete cuerpos celestes, que en sus orbes particulares tiene cada uno su propio movimiento, contrario al del primer mobil: y por esta razón se llamaron errantes, à diferencia de las demás estrellas que estan fixas en el Cielo. Son sus nombres **Sol, Luna**, Marte, Mercurio, Jupiter, Venus y Saturno, de quien tomaron nombres los siete días de la semána.

---

A pesar de que, según recoge [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redefinici%C3%B3n_de_planeta_de_2006#Procedimiento_del_24_de_agosto) en 2006 la Unión Astronómica Internacional adoptó una redefinición de "planeta", por la que Plutón pasa a ser un *planeta enano* y `los planetas del sistema solar son Mercurio, Venus, Tierra, Marte, Júpiter, Saturno, Urano y Neptuno.`, la definición en la actualidad en el DLE de [planeta](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TJiMVcb) es:

> 1. m. Cuerpo celeste sin luz propia que gira en una órbita elíptica alrededor de una estrella, en particular los que giran alrededor del Sol: Mercurio, Venus, la Tierra, Marte, Júpiter, Saturno, Urano, Neptuno y **Plutón**.

---

Cuando se descubrieron los dinosaurios se creyó que eran reptiles enormes, de ahí la palabra; *dinosaurio* significa, etimológicamente, *lagarto terrible*. Sin embargo, hace ya muchos años que se sabe que no es así y que, de hecho, dinosaurios y reptiles no tienen nada que ver. Ambas clases aparecieron de forma independiente y más o menos simultánea hace unos 200 millones de años. Sin embargo, a día de hoy, la única acepción de la palabra [dinosaurio](https://dle.rae.es/?id=DojjUme) en el DLE sigue siendo:

> 1. m. Reptil fósil de gran tamaño, con cabeza pequeña, cuello largo, cola robusta y larga, y, en general, extremidades posteriores más largas que las anteriores. U. a veces c. adj.

En realidad, los únicos descendientes vivos de los dinosaurios son las aves. La definición del DLE podría sustituir *reptil fósil* por *animal ya extinto* y, sin pretender ser correcta desde el punto de vista científico, sería mucho más válida e igualmente comprensible desde el punto de vista lingüístico.

---

La definición actual de [pez](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SqyV2F4) es:

> 1. m. Vertebrado acuático, de respiración branquial, generalmente con extremidades en forma de aleta, aptas para la locomoción y sustentación en el agua. La piel, salvo raras excepciones, está protegida por escamas. La forma de reproducción es ovípara en la mayoría de estos animales. U. t. en pl. como taxón.

Pero Alfonso L Rojo en [«Inconsistencias, incorrecciones, atraso y errores en las definiciones de términos relativos a la Ictiología en el Diccionario 2001 de la Real Academia de la Lengua Española (RAE).»](https://web.archive.org/web/20131016215802/http://husky1.smu.ca/%7Earojo/InconsistenciasNuevaPage.pdf) recoge varios errores de esa definición:

> ... *de respiración branquial*, es incompleta. Hay peces modernos pulmonados en Australia, Sudáfrica y Suramérica de los géneros Neoceratodus, Protopterus y Lepidosiren respectivamente, que respiran por branquias *y pulmones*.
> ... [aletas] *aptas para la locomoción* es científicamente falsa. Solamente sirven para la locomoción en casos reducidos y para pequeños desplazamientos. Es más, se le pueden cortar las aletas a un pez y sigue viviendo y desplazándose. ... En resumidas cuentas, a pesar de que todas las partes del pez participan en este proceso de una manera activa o pasiva, las contracciones de los músculos del cuerpo y de la cola son el factor fundamental del movimiento.
> ... ["*las aletas son aptas para la sustentación en el agua.*"] Sí, en algunos casos y solamente de manera indirecta. La sustentación se lleva a cabo en la
> mayoría de los peces teleósteos modernos por medio de la vejiga, mal llamada natatoria, ya que no sirve para nadar.

En el mismo texto indica los errores presentes en las definiciones de [lamprea](https://dle.rae.es/?id=MrKz0DJ), [tiburón](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZiO2u8j), [lija](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NJVBCCN), [esturión](https://dle.rae.es/?id=H2uIpOx), etc.

---

A través de [Archiletras](https://www.archiletras.com/deslenguado/humildad-academica/), descubro la etimología de **galilea<sup>2</sup>** según el DLE (negrita mía):

> [**galilea**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=IkZScQm)
> `Del lat.` *`[et ecce praecedit vos in] Galileam`*`'[y he aquí el que os precede a] Galilea', Mateo, XXVIII, 7,`**`palabras de Jesucristo.`**

> 1. f. En la Iglesia griega, tiempo que media entre la Pascua de Resurrección y la Ascensión.

El problema es que, si nos vamos a [Mateo 28](https://www.bible.com/es/bible/146/MAT.28.RVC), 5-7, podemos comprobar que esas palabras las dijo un ángel, no Jesucristo:

> <sup>5</sup>Pero el ángel les dijo a las mujeres: «No teman. Yo sé que buscan a Jesús, el que fue crucificado.
> <sup>6</sup>No está aquí, pues ha resucitado, como él dijo. Vengan y vean el lugar donde fue puesto el Señor.
> <sup>7</sup>Luego, vayan pronto y digan a sus discípulos que él ha resucitado de los muertos. De hecho, va delante de ustedes a Galilea; allí lo verán. Ya se lo he dicho.»

Por lo visto, este error ha estado presente desde la primera inclusión de la palabra en 1884:

[image]

---

Hasta la edición de 1884 inclusive, la RAE definía (incorrectamente) a la **rana** como un **reptil**; a partir de 1899 ya lo define (correctamente) como *batracio*.

[image]

Comment: @Alicia sí, y historicamente la palabra se usaba así, aún en esa época. Mira a una entrada de un [diccionario inglés contemporánea](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CoRZAAAAcAAJ&q=planet) (1730) que también incluye el sol y la luna en su descripción, y no la tierra hasta ~[1792](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bXsCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PP9&q=planet)

Comment: The commentary on dinosaurs/reptiles is incorrect on many levels. Most colloquial and all cladistic definitions of reptile/reptilia I am familiar with include non-avian dinosaurs in the definition. Reptiles is a group containing dinosaurs, much like mammals is a group containing apes.

Comment: The commentary on planets is also problematic. Just because one organisation or group uses a word in a specific way in their context doesn't mean other definitions of the word do not have currency. These definitions aren't 'wrong' - these are accurate descriptions of how the words were used by most people in Spain at the time. They may be *incomplete*, not including (at the time) minority or only specifically scientific parallel usages of the word however.